# How to implement jQuery Tokeninput to Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, qualtrics, jquery-tokeninput

I'm quite new to jquery.

Looking to implement the tokeninput plugin [(Link to plugin)](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

into a qualtrics survey.  I'm not quite sure where to put things and the like.  Have been doing research and will continue to do so, but thought I'd try to ask here.

I've already figured out how to get an autocomplete system implemented, but feel like this specific plugin will serve my needs more completely.

Thanks!

Comment: Integrating the prototype version of Chosen will probably be easier: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/index.proto.html

Comment: That looks perfect. Thank you